AggregateReference not populated for dto with @NoArgsConstructor
I'm loving Spring Data JDBC, but have come across something which I wonder if it's a bug, or intended behaviour.
When I'm loading data from a repository, and have an AggregateReference in my Model, it is not populating an identical DTO from the Repository, UNLESS I specify my own query.
In my test case (before customizing my DTO), my Model and DTO are identical (other than the @Table annotation.)  As follows (for clarity):
Model
@NoArgsConstructor
@Getter
@Setter
@Table
public class Product {
    @Id
    private Long id;
    private String name;
    private AggregateReference<ProductType,Long> productType;
}

DTO
@NoArgsConstructor
@Getter
@Setter
public class ProductDTO {
        private Long id;
        private String name;
        private AggregateReference<ProductType,Long> productType;
}

My Repository
public interface ProductRepository extends ListCrudRepository<Product, Long> {
    List<Product> findAll();
    List<ProductDTO> findAllBy();
}

The findAll method, loads the AggregateReference, as expected, BUT the findAllBy doesn't - it is null.
However, if I specify my query explicitly, as follows, it works perfectly.
...
    @Query("""
        SELECT
            p.*
        FROM product p
""")
    List<ProductDTO> findAllBy();
...

What am I missing?

Have you tried to name it
List<ProductDTO> findAll();

instead
List<ProductDTO> findAllBy();

?

Yes, this seems to be a bug. There is a PR and I hope I'll be able to merge that soon.
